# Windows 10; crash after few minutes after startup; restarts and never crashes again until a power off

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash, reboot, debug

I turn on my computer. Windows 10 boots up and the desktop appears. I login and get to do my work. After a few minutes, the computer restarts by itself suddenly (no BSOD). Windows boots up and I get to do my work. However, it does not crash again.

If I shut down my computer and start it again, Windows crashes then restarts and everything starts working as it should.

Why is Windows crashing on the first boot after a shutdown?

What is the procedure to investigate the cause?

---

**Auto-Reboot disabled**

Auto-Reboot on crash is disabled but BSOD still does not appear.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl\Auto-Reboot` is set to 0.

**Event Log**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9F2AyeWVnHQ

Comment: BSOD only appears when you ask Windows to show it. Normally, Windows just logs the BSOD and restarts. So, what I am saying is: It still can be a BSOD.

Comment: Take a look at the system event logs.

Comment: I have auto-reboot disabled. So something must have gone horribly wrong that Windows failed to catch it?

Comment: @David I had the system event log system disabled (have enabled it now; let's see what that has for us). If I try to open the minidump, my VS2015 says "debugging older format crashdumps is not supported". It is weird that the BSOD does not appear but Windows manages to create a dump. So I guess Windows had control before the reboot.

Comment: The "Auto-Reboot" field in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl` is set to 0.

Comment: Oh nevermind. The minidumps are few months old. They are unrelated to this event. So Windows probably crashed unexpectedly and did not have any control to create a crashdump.

Comment: not very helpful, but at a last resort you could simply refresh windows

Answer (score 0):

We could try run startup repair:
press and hold the SHIFT key on your keyboard and click Restart. 
Then select
**Troubleshoot ->Advanced options ->startup repair** 
In addition, check if you have any abnormal schedule task running to trigger the restart. 
If no, perform a [Clean Boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) to eliminate the third-party software conflict.

Comment: The desktop window appears and I can use the computer for a while before it restarts. I don't think there is an issue with startup. I'll try a clean boot next time.